# Greater Than Proposition for an if and only if statement (Exponent is 2)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have been trying to prove this proposition. There could be a counterexample, but I do not think there is. It looks like the algebra would be easy but for some reason I keep trying to prove it and find myself stuck. Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

> Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$. Thus, $x>y$ if and only if $x^2>y^2$.

Comment: Which direction of the if and only if implication did you try first?

Comment: There are two implications to prove, one in one direction and one in the other. Are you stuck on both? It might help if you showed your work, especially the part(s) you couldn't finish.

Comment: I can not do either. I might be able to get the other one if I see one way.

Comment: The $\geq0$ part is essential. Neither direction works if all you have is $x,y\in\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$. For the first direction, since both numbers are nonnegative and both cannot be zero at the same time, their sum is positive, and by assumption $x-y>0$. Thus $x^2-y^2>0$. For the other direction, we have $x+y>0$ since both numbers are nonnegative and if both were zero then $x^2=y^2$. Thus dividing both sides of the inequality by $x+y $ gives $x-y>0$.

Answer (score 0):

A hint: the $\geq0$ part is essential. Neither direction works if all you have is $x,y\in\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

Given x> y then, since $x\ge 0%, $x(x)= x^2\ge xy$.  Since $y\ge 0$ $xy\ge y(y)= y^2$.   Together, $x^2\ge xy\ge y^2$ so $x^2\ge y^2$.

Given $x^2> y^2$ then $x^2- y^2= (x- y)(x+ y)> 0$. Since x and y are non-negative, x+ y is non-negative. x and y cannot both be 0 since then $x^2$ would not be greater than $y^2$.  So we must have x+ y> 0.  Dividing both sides of (x- y)(x+ y)> 0, x- y> 0 so x> y.